# class forward declaration in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

namespace AAH 
{
    class messageTemplate;
};

using namespace AAH;

int main()
{
    messageTemplate templateMSG32("hello world");
    cout << templateMSG32.version << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

namespace AAH {    
    class messageTemplate 
    {
    public:
        messageTemplate() : version("XX.XX.XX.001") {}
        messageTemplate(string ver) : version(ver) {}
        string version;
    };
};
```

ok this is the code,

I get an error message:

`Error  3   error C2228: left of '.version' must have class/struct/union`

I am using `visual studio 2012`

can anyone tell me why I am getting this error

Comment: You can't use object without it's prototype declared.
Forward declaration is good only to let you declare a pointer or reference.

Comment: I thought forward declaration is like a function prototype

Comment: Think about how should `sizeof` work. It can't be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use object without it's prototype declared. Forward declaration is good only to let you declare a pointer or reference without include and add lot of dependencies.

In header files you don't want many unnecessary includes. many include can cause long compilation time. therefore when you just need to declare a pointer or a reference, in class or function prototypes, it is good idea to use forward declaration instead of include.

look at the sample:

**file A.h**

```
class A{
public:
    void func() const;
};
```

**file B.h**

```
//fwd declaration instead of include
class A;

class B{
public:
  //use fwd decl.
  B(const A& a);
};
```

**file B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h" //have to include since I using the obj.
B::B(const A& a){
   a.func();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that whats going on, but I have never used forward declaration before, always use include in anywhere I use the class :D thank you for the clearance

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above forward declaration only let's you declare pointers or references.

In your example you don't technically need forward declaration because you can just declare the AAH class before the main function.